# Extending contrib module filelog service class displays PSR implementation error

Tags: 9, log-messages, symfony-services

I wanted to override the logger.filelog service from [filelog](https://www.drupal.org/project/filelog) module to make use of my own parser.

An error occurred through `drush cim` and `drush cr` when the new custom module that overrides the service is enabled.

```php
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException: Service 'logger.filelog' for consumer 'logger.factory' does not implement Psr\Log\LoggerInterface. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->processServiceCollectorPass() (line 182 of /app/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TaggedHandlersPass.php).
```

My custom modules structure looks like this

```
custom_module
  - src
    - Logger
      - TestFilelog.php
    CustomModuleServiceProvider.php
  custom_module.info.yml
  custom_module.module
```

Currently the service provider class has implemented `ServiceModifierInterface`
and altered the original logger.filelog service by setting its class to `Drupal\custom_module\Logger\TestFilelog`.

```php
/**
 * Class to override contrib module logger.filelog service.
 */
class CustomModuleServiceProvider implements ServiceModifierInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    if ($container->has('logger.filelog')) {
      $definition = $container->getDefinition('logger.filelog');
      $definition->setClass('Drupal\custom_module\Logger\TestFilelog');
    }
  }

}
```

`TestFilelog.php`

```
namespace Drupal\custom_module\Logger;

use Drupal\filelog\Logger\FileLog;

/**
 * File-based logger.
 */
class TestFileLog extends FileLog {

  /**
   * Renders a message to a string.
   *
   * @param mixed $level
   *   Severity level of the log message.
   * @param string $message
   *   Content of the log message.
   * @param array $context
   *   Context of the log message.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The formatted message.
   */
  protected function render($level, $message, array $context = []): string {

    $plainString = parent::render($level, $message, $context);

    $custom_channel = [
      'filter_custom_channel'
    ];

    if (in_array($context['channel'], $custom_channel)) {
      $plainString = $this->parseStrMasking($plainString);
    }
    return $plainString;
  }

  /**
   * Mask personal details from strings to logs.
   *
   * @param string $pureString
   *   The string to be parsed.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The string that has been masked.
   */
  protected function parseStrMasking(string $pureString) {
    // Default to return finalString.
    $finalString = $pureString;
    
    // Custom parsing goes here.
    
    return $finalString;
  }

}
```

I see that `Drupal\filelog\Logger\FileLog;` has `use RfcLoggerTrait;` which does implement the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`, what am I missing here??

Comment: Your code works fine for me - have you tried restarting Apache/PHP-FPM?

Comment: You do have a small discrepancy though - you're mixing the casing of `TestFileLog` (it's `Testfilelog` in the filename and service alter). Might make a difference if you're on a case-sensitive file system

Comment: OMG @Clive you are absolutely right! Kudos for you mate!

Comment: FYI, while struggling last night, I'd discovered another way to override the contrib module's service through custom_module.services.yml. It works, so I made use of it instead. Thanks for your effort on testing and reading through, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Clive in the comment above, I had a discrepancy in the casing of `TestFilelog` and `TestFileLog`. Thanks again!

This should make a difference on why the implementation of interface wasn't read by Drupal on service handling.

On the other hand, I discovered another approach to override `filelog` module's service, which I took instead.

1. I deleted the `CustomModuleServiceProvider.php` file
2. Created `custom_module.services.yml`
3. service machine name should be the same as the overridden service. (e.g. logger.filelog) 
    Check `docroot/modules/contrib/filelog/filelog.services.yml`

Content of `custom_module.services.yml`

```yaml
services:
  logger.filelog:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\Logger\TestFileLog
    arguments:
      - '@config.factory'
      - '@state'
      - '@token'
      - '@datetime.time'
      - '@logger.log_message_parser'
      - '@filelog.file_manager'
    tags:
      - { name: logger }
```

**Ref:**

1. [How to decorate Services - Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)
2. [Altering existing services - Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic)
3. [Overriding services in Drupal - PreviousNext](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/overriding-services-drupal-8-advanced-cases)

Comment: Redefining the service like that would be my last choice. Better choices are the way you did it in the original question, or by decoration. The reason is that defining your own logger.filelog in the services.yml file does nothing to indicate that this is an overridden service - the intention of the programmer is obscured (was it just a mistake that a previously-named service was used?). Also, what happens if the Filelog module is loaded *after* your module - which service actually gets defined, yours or the Filelog service? And what happens if another module overrides logger.filelog?

Comment: Oh dear! Your concern do have a point, maybe I should refine it back to the original format and check that it works. On the other hand, is there other resources that I may reference in decoration of service? I only read that decoration extends the original service, but while implementing it, I don't actually know how I should override the original service with a decorate service.
Cheers!

Comment: This is a pretty good article which should help: https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-symfony-service-decorators-drupal-8

Comment: Thanks for the info, this article has been really helpful as it written every detail of their consideration and thinking process.